# IIS - Releasing handle to folder by w3wp.exe so it can be renamed

Tags: batch-file, iis, tfs, tfsbuild, w3wp

I have a TFS build process that drops outputs on sandbox which is another server in the same network. In other words, the build agent and sandbox are separate machines. After the outputs are created, a batch script defined within the build template does the following:

- Rename existing deployment folder to some prefix + timestamp (IIS can now no longer find the app when users attempt to access it)
- Move newly-created outputs to deployment location

The reason why I wanted to rename and move files instead of copy/delete/overwrite is the latter takes a lot of time because we have so many files (over 5500). I'm trying to find a way to complete builds in the shortest amount of time possible to increase developer productivity. I hope to create a windows service to delete dump folders and drop folder artifacts periodically so sandbox doesn't fill up.

The problem I'm facing is IIS maintains a handle to the original deployment folder so the batch script cannot rename it. I used `Process Explorer` to see what process is using the folder. It's `w3wp.exe` which is a worker process for the application pool my app sits in. I tried killing all `w3wp.exe` instances before renaming the folder, but this did not work. I then decided to stop the application pool, rename the folder, and start it again. This did not work either.

In either case, `Process Explorer` showed that there were still uncollected handles to my outputs except this time the owner name wasn't `w3wp.exe`, but it was something along the lines of unidentified process. At one point, I saw that the owner was `System`, but killing System's process tree shuts down the server.

Is there any way to properly remove all handles to my deployment folder so the batch script can safely rename it?

Comment: _I then decided to stop the application pool, rename the folder..._ In what way did it not work? I'd expect that stopping the app pool would unlock the folder. Can you use the tasks described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2009/10/22/which-w3wp-exe-pid-corresponds-to-which-application-pool.aspx. to confirm that the application pool has stopped as expected? Killing it won't help as IIS is built to automatically restart crashed IIS processes (in this case crashed because you killed it!). It seems like you need to do some more investigation into this 'unidentified process'

Comment: Are you avoiding stopping IIS entirely?  If not, `iisreset /stop`, rename files, then `iisreset /start`.  If you're concerned about your web site going offline during the deployment, you could use Visual Studio's `webdev.webserver.exe` as a temporary replacement while you perform your maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Use windows systernal tool called Handle v4.0

Answer (score 0):

Tools like `Process Explorer`, that can find and forcibly close file handles, however the state and behaviour of the application (both yours and, in this case, IIS) after doing this is undefined. Some won't care, some will error and others will crash hard.

The correct solution is to allow IIS to cleanly release locks and clean up after itself to preserve server stability. If this is not possible, you can either create another site on the same box, or set up a new box with the new content, and move the domain name/IP across to "promote" the new content to production